# Which line in each pair (below) is correct?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

As a trainer of English as second language, the following statements have caused much dismay among my students. Kindly help clarify. 
Which line in each pair (below) is correct?

1. They are all there but me or 
   They are all there but I
2. Who do you take me for?
   Whom do you take me for?
3. I would not do that if I were him.
   I would not do that if I were he
4. He answered more questions than I.
   He answered more questions than me.
5. They are wiser than us.
   They are wiser than we.
6. We are poorer than they.
   We are poorer than them.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Interesting question. Strictly speaking the correct forms are "He answered more questions than I [did]", "They are wiser than we [are]", and "We are poorer than they [are]", but I think many people would consider the alternative versions quite acceptable in everyday speech.

Comment: These are four unrelated questions in one. And all have been asked and answered before. Please use the site search, or browse the tags. Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, (1) makes no sense either way, because "they" never includes "me" to begin with. It would need to be something like "everyone but me" instead.

Comment: An ESL teacher really ought to avoid dangling modifiers.